# A decreasing sequence of Lebesgue measureable sets

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to find an example of a decreasing sequence $\{E_n\}$ of Lebesgue measurable sets such that $m(\bigcap ^\infty_{n=1} E_n)\neq \lim _{n\to\infty} m(E_n)$.

I feel like whether the measure of the set is finite or infinite matters.
I have no idea....
I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, just look at an infinite measure space (that is, $m(S)=\infty$, where $S$ is the whole space).  You cannot get examples otherwise.  Might as well take $S = \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E_n = [n,+\infty).$ Then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n = \varnothing,$ which has measure $0,$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} m\left(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right) = +\infty.$

Now suppose instead $E_n$ are some other sets and one of $E_n$ has finite measure. No generality is lost by assuming it's $E_1.$ Now let
$$
A_n = E_n \smallsetminus \bigcap_{m=n+1}^\infty.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
& +\infty>m(E_n) \\[8pt]
= {} & m\left(A_n \cup A_{n+1} \cup A_{n+2} \cup \cdots\cup \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty E_m\right) \\[8pt]
= {} & m(A_n) + m(A_2) + m(A_3) + \cdots + m\left( \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty E_m \right) \\[8pt]
\to {} & \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty E_m \text{ as } n\to\infty \text{ since the series converges.}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much! But, would you please explain why $\bigcap ^\infty _{n=1} E_n =\emptyset$? I don't know how to measure a set such that $(\infty, \infty)$

Comment: @measurehell $$ \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [n,+\infty) = \varnothing$$ because there is no number that is a member of all of the sets $[n,+\infty). \qquad$

Comment: Can I ask what is the measure of $[n,\infty)$

Comment: @user726608 : It is $+\infty.$ The set of values of the Lebesgue measure on the line is $[0,+\infty],$ an interval that is closed at both ends. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that measures are continuous from below/above with respect to (increasing unions)/ (decreasing intersections) of measurable sets. Formally, you can show that if $E_{n+1}\subseteq E_n$ and at least one $E_k$ has finite measure, then you'll get equality. So the only alternative is either some of your $E_n$ are not measurable, or if all of them have infinite measure.

E.g. if $m$ is Lebesgue measure, then take $E_n=(n,\infty)$, so that $E_\infty=\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: Do the examples work for $\mu$ not specifically lebasgue measure, where $E_n\in{A}$ and $(X,\mu,A)$ a measure space?

Comment: @user726608: It should be true for arbitrary measures, so long as at least one $E_i$ has finite measure.

Comment: I'm trying to find a measure-space $(X,A,\mu)$ ,not lebesgue measure, and a decreasing sequence $En$ that satisfy the above condition..the problem is that I'm not managing to define a proper measure (as in definition). Can u help..